# how to get result in iteration ids in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

how to get result in iteration ids in ajax call ...the result should be in iteration ids but...the result doesnt display.how to get dsplay results in php ajax call in for loop iteration ids?.

here is my html code

```
<tr>
                      <td><span id="sr_no">1</span></td>
                      <td><select type="text" name="item_name[]" id="item_name1" class="form-control input-sm"  onChange="getbrand(this.value);" />
                      <option value=""></option>
                      <?php
    include "conn.php";
    $sql = "SELECT category FROM `product` GROUP BY category";
    $run = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))
    {
    ?>
<option><?php echo $row['category']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
                      </select>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <select type="text" name="item_name[]" id="brand" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        <option value=""></option>

                        </select>
                      </td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm order_item_quantity" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_price" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate1" data-srno="1" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount1" data-srno="1" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>
                      <td></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  <div align="right">
                    <button type="button" name="add_row" id="add_row" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">+</button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

here is my java script

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var final_total_amt = $('#final_total_amt').text();
        var count = 1;

        $(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
          count++;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
          var html_code = '';
          html_code += '<tr id="row_id_'+count+'">';
          html_code += '<td><span id="sr_no">'+count+'</span></td>';

         html_code += '<td><select name="item_name[]" id="item_name'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" onChange="getbrand(this.value);" ><option></option><?php $sql='Select category from product GROUP BY category'; $run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){ echo '<option>'.$row['category'].'</option>'; } ?></select></td>';

          html_code += '<td><select name="brand[]" id="brand'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm" ><option></option></select></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_quantity[]" id="order_item_quantity'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_quantity" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_price[]" id="order_item_price'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_price" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_actual_amount[]" id="order_item_actual_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm order_item_actual_amount" readonly /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_rate[]" id="order_item_tax1_rate'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" class="form-control input-sm number_only order_item_tax1_rate" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_tax1_amount[]" id="order_item_tax1_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_tax1_amount" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><input type="text" name="order_item_final_amount[]" id="order_item_final_amount'+count+'" data-srno="'+count+'" readonly class="form-control input-sm order_item_final_amount" /></td>';

          html_code += '<td><button type="button" name="remove_row" id="'+count+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs remove_row">X</button></td>';
          html_code += '</tr>';
          $('#invoice-item-table').append(html_code);
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove_row', function(){
          var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
          var total_item_amount = $('#order_item_final_amount'+row_id).val();
          var final_amount = $('#final_total_amt').text();
          var result_amount = parseFloat(final_amount) - parseFloat(total_item_amount);
          $('#final_total_amt').text(result_amount);
          $('#row_id_'+row_id).remove();
          count--;
          $('#total_item').val(count);
        });


function getbrand(count) {
 for(k=1; k<=count; k++)
          {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_brand.php",
data:'state_id='+val,
success: function(data){ 

$("#brand"+k).html(data);
}
});}
}
</script>
```

my question for this script .....how to add iteration for ids in this ajax call.

```
function getbrand(count) {
     for(k=1; k<=count; k++)
              {


     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_brand.php",
        data:'state_id='+val,
        success: function(data){ 

        $("#brand"+k).html(data);
        }
        });}
        }
```

Comment: I assume you have multiple `tr` of each brand having brand id in sequence. correct?

Comment: ya..right Yash Parekh

Comment: Just give the id as `brand1` to the first static html and then the rest will be start from `brand2` and so on.. Seems like perfect. Where you are facing difficulty?

Comment: if i select category then display all brand of the selected category from database in brand ids using php and ajax call

Comment: After the ajax return, are you adding available drop down list option to a specific list or adding a whole new drop down list base on the ajax response?

Comment: the dropdown of brand is based on ajax response

Comment: all new tr of brand have diiferent options using selecting category

Answer (score 0):

Since we do not have the format on how data would be like returned from ajax_brand.php, I assume that is a array of brand id and brand name entry.

E.g.

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Brand 1"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Brand 2"
   }
]
```

Then the success of the ajax should be something like this. Of course, you need to substitute the id `brand1` with your for loop `k` counter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button-fire').on('click', function() {
    handleFire();
  });
});



function handleFire() {

  var brandSelect = $('#brand1').empty();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // mock url
    url: "http://5b6a940cad81cd0014d152d2.mockapi.io/brand/api/v1/brands",
    success: function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(brand) {
        brandSelect.append($('<option>', {
            value: brand.id
          }).html(brand.name)

        );
      });

    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="brand[]" id="brand1" class="form-control input-sm">
  <option></option>
</select>



<button id="button-fire">fire</button>
```